# Unable to click and proceed on [Login] button using Watir Webdriver

Tags: ruby, selenium, google-chrome, watir

Trying to programmatically *click* and proceed on the following [Log in] button.

```
<input type="image" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnLogin2" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_btnLogin2" src="/images/buttons/log-in.gif" onclick="return onClick(event);">
```

I've attempted the following using Watir+WebDriver+ChromeDriver:

```
browser.button(id: 'ContentPlaceHolder1_btnLogin2').click
```

the above returns nothing and exits browser.

```
browser.button(id: 'ContentPlaceHolder1_btnLogin2').fire_event "onclick"
```

the above returns 'false' and exits browser.

The Webrdriver-chromedriver in use is version '71.0.3578.33'

Comment: 1. Make sure you are using the same version of Chrome as chromedriver; you can use the `webdrivers` gem to make sure they always match.
2. Is it a timing issue? Can you put in a sleep to see if there is an en activity that hasn't loaded yet when the click is supposed to happen?
3. I don't understand the "exits the browser" part. Is there no code after? Is there an error message? To get more information, you can turn on the logger: `Watir.logger.level = :info`

Comment: @titusfortner - It supposed to login into the site, instead it just closes the browser.
The chromedriver & webdriver match as it works on other pages.

Comment: It should still work when they versions don't match, except in weird places where it doesn't. So there is code after the login that is not getting executed? Or are you intending for the browser not to get closed when the code is complete?

Comment: @titusfortner I think `onclick="return onClick(event);` is not firing

Comment: ok, we're talking past each other. A click event sent to the driver will fire all applicable events. If it works manually, but isn't working with code, then we need to make sure it's the right code (driver version & browser version actually match), and that there isn't a timing issue (so temporarily put a long sleep before & after the click to see if it makes a difference)

Comment: @titusfortner I added a `sleep 10` after the`browser.button(id: 'ContentPlaceHolder1_btnLogin2').click` statement and it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify what error you were getting or what you are trying to do after the click, but it is possible that the click hasn't finished before you attempt to do the next thing. You can use a sleep command to determine if there is an issue, but I highly recommend figuring out what comes next and making an explicit wait for that to occur, rather than just using a sleep statement.

Answer (score -1):

It's not working because that's not button its an image, so use this code

```
browser.image(id: 'ContentPlaceHolder1_btnLogin2').click
```

Comment: Actually, that's not true, because it is in an input tag: https://github.com/watir/watir/blob/master/lib/watir/elements/button.rb#L11

Comment: But it's type is image, no? So using `image` works!

Comment: hmm, it probably should, but I don't think it actually does.

Comment: @Rajagopalan It is an <input> tag with type='image' according to Watir documentation http://watir.com/watir/doc/Watir/Button.html the button class covers both <button> and <input type="submit|reset|image|button" /> elements.

Comment: `button` can refer to an element with the button tag directly, or one of those input types in the link. `image` just refers to the image tag directly. Either `button` or `input` should work for this example, but not `image`.

Comment: @Rajagopalan The  browser.image(id: 'ContentPlaceHolder1_btnLogin2').click code does not work. Watir fails to find element

Comment: @titusfortner I used in many places like this in the past and it worked.

Comment: @arnoldtm Okay, can you try this? `browser.input(id: 'ContentPlaceHolder1_btnLogin2').click`